# Method in child class doesn't get called by virtual function in parent class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

In my application, I have several readers which read data out of .csv files. I want to structure them now by creating a parent class for those readers which have in common that they own the method `getData(std::string filename)`. I wanted to do it by implementing a virtual method in the base class. The filename should be passed by the constructor.

main

```
int main()
{
    std::string filename = "file.csv";
    ChildReader1 reader = new ChildReader1(filename);
}
```

ChildReader1.h

```
class ChildReader1: public ParentReader
    {
    public:
        ChildReader1(std::string filename)
            : ParentReader(filename)
        {

        };
        void getData(std::string filename)
        {
             //get the data here
        }
    };
```

ParentReader.h

```
class ParentReader
    {
    public:
        ParentReader() {};
        ParentReader(std::string filename)
        {
            getData(filename);
        };
        ~ParentReader() {};

        virtual void getData(std::string filename) {};
    };
```

At the moment, filename is passed to ParentReader but the getData(filename) opens the virtual method in ParentReader instead of the actual method in ChildReader 1. How can I solve that?

Comment: The virtual methods are not called during construction of the base (parent) class. Because the the derived is not ready yet.

Comment: Okay, so how can I call the method that lies in the subclass in the base class?

Comment: If you want to call the child method then you have to create a child object.

Comment: @Stefan, This introduces a dependency of your base class on its derived classes. You have to do it in the derived classes' constructors

Comment: Call `getData` from `ChildReader1`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can't call a virtual method on a derived class in a base class constructor as the derived class is not ready yet.

One solution is to have a factory function on `ChildReader1`:

```
class ParentReader {
public:
  ParentReader(){};
  void initialize(const std::string& filename){
    getData(filename);
  };
  virtual ~ParentReader(){};
  virtual void getData(const std::string& /*filename*/) {
  };
};

class ChildReader1 : public ParentReader {
private:
  ChildReader1(){}
public:
  void getData(const std::string& /*filename*/) override {
    // get the data here
  }
  static std::unique_ptr<ChildReader1> create(const std::string &filename) {
    auto reader = std::unique_ptr<ChildReader1>(new ChildReader1);
    reader->initialize(filename);
    return reader;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::string filename = "file.csv";
  auto reader = ChildReader1::create(filename);
}
```

The factory function creates a fully formed object and can then call virtual functions before returning. You can make the constructor of the object private to force callers to use your factory function.

To avoid code duplication between  derived classes you could introduce an intermediate CRTP class.

Comment: @Jarod42 is better and more general

Comment: Also if the parent holds all data and the child only loads it you can pass it as function to the parent constructor.

Comment: @AA Jarod42's is good. One issue with doing it that way is there is nothing preventing a caller from calling the constructor directly and ending up with an unloaded reader.

Comment: But this could be fixed by hiding the constructor and making the template a friend. Also these factory solutions are not exception safe - you can get an not `initialize`d object and it's better to use `std::make_unique` instead of the `new`.

Comment: @AA the use of `new` and not `make_unique` is due to the constructor being private, there are ways around it but I thought it was out-of-scope of this question. In what way is it not exception safe? If initialize throws an exception then the local reader in the factory function is deleted.

Comment: The private constructor shouldn't be a problem because you already use it with new, but maybe you have only C++11 and have no make_unique?

Comment: @AA `std::make_unique` can't construct a class with a private constructor -- [Try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I5Kd082wifTxISCe)

Comment: You're right. Good point. Looks like there some workarownds http://seanmiddleditch.com/enabling-make_unique-with-private-constructors/ and here http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-5/true-story-when-friendship-smothers#what-about-utility-functions'-utility-functions

Answer (score 2):

You might solve your issue with a factory:

```
class ParentReader
{
public:
    virtual ~ParentReader() = default
    virtual void getData(const std::string& filename) = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<T> MakeReader(const std::string& filename, Ts&&... args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<ParentReader, T>::value, "!");
    auto res = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    res->getData(filename);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The virtual methods are not called during construction of the base (parent) class. Because the the derived is not ready yet.

12.7 Construction and destruction [class.cdtor] #4 ISO/IEC N3797

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called during construction or destruction (12.6.2). When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the call applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction, the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class. If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not x or one of its base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, you should not call virtual function in constructor. The reason is quite simple if you think about what is happening:

call of ChildConstructor -> call of ParentConstructor -> creation of Parent -> call of getData -> creation of Child

At the call of getData the only existing object is the Parent therefore it can't possibly call the getData of the Child.